# What is the blue-white-blue horizontal triband flag waved by karateka Sandra Sánchez at the Tokyo 2020 Olympics?

Tags: spain, flag

On winning the gold medal in the women’s kata event at the Tokyo 2020 Olympics, Sandra Sánchez waved a blue-white-blue horizontal triband flag with a coat of arms in the center. The coat of arms includes a crown on top of what seems to be a fortified tower with a red background.

I am trying to find out what this flag represents. I searched through [flags of autonomous communities in Spain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flags_of_the_autonomous_communities_of_Spain) and [flags of Spanish cities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Flags_of_cities_in_Spain), and also tried to use flagid.org, but couldn’t find it.

The full flag can be seen in [this YouTube video from Eurosport](https://youtu.be/oN6WtMVkpVU?t=319) (at 5:19). I am also posting a partial screenshot showing the colors and coat of arms here:

[image: Partial screenshot of mysterious flag]

---

For anyone wondering if this question is within the scope of this site, [it is according to this Meta discussion](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4729/when-are-questions-about-flag-identification-on-topic).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is the flag of Sánchez's hometown, [Talavera de la Reina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talavera_de_la_Reina), in Castile–La Mancha.

[image]
<sub>Source: [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bandera_de_Talavera.svg)</sub>